# Samba sharing problem

Tags: mate, samba4

Hi I installed ubuntu mate (Life) version as a LTSP server.
My problem is when I share a folder from my desktop or anywhere else it gives me an error message:
"Failed to mount windows share: invalid argument"
My ubuntu mate version is 22.04
And samba version is 4.15.9
Kindly tell me what should I do to solve this problem.
I have tried lots of troubleshoot from internet but could not solve it.
Thanks

Comment: Please provide some more info. E.g. IP addresses of source and client, the command you are issuing..

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: John Ronald i have workgroup environment my server ip address i 192.168.10.11 i have read different solutions somebody say add "force user= username i did that somebody say change home folder permission to 755 i did this but problem not solve